# Border not working in IE

Tags: css, css-selectors, border

I want to apply border to elements which

1. Have `.xforms-required` class and not a `span` element OR
2. `input` elements which are descendent of the element which have `.xforms-required` class

So I come up with

```
.xforms-required:not(span), .xforms-required input {
    border: 1px solid gold !important;
}
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kYGhn/).

Its  working fine in Firefox 18.0.1 and not working in IE (Tested in IE 8).
Not sure whether something is wrong with the CSS selector or the `border` attribute.

Facing some problem with jsFiddle in IE so wrote a short snippet for the same

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            .xforms-required:not(span), .xforms-required input {
                border: 1px solid gold !important;
            }
        </style>
        <span class="xforms-required">
            <input>  // This should get border 
        </span>    
        <input class="xforms-required"> // This should get border    
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for might be silly question but not a CSS guy so..

---

As [Adrift](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783413/adrift) pointed out that `:not()` is supported in IE9+, any other alternative to achieve the same in IE7+ versions

Comment: IE8 only supports css 2.1, your selectors are css 3. You can use jQuery to solve it.

Comment: `:not()` isn't supported below IE 9 - http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: @ZippyV: I would love to use jQuery but cant use it. Need pure CSS soultion

Comment: @Adrift: Oops any other alternative which will work in IE 7+ versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
input.xforms-required, .xforms-required input {
    border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

Optional:

```
span.xforms-required {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting comments to answer: IE8 does not support `:not()`. You will need to find some other way to define your selector. Maybe `input.xforms-required, .xforms-required input`